# What is the best way to create dynamic time-based events like building construction times,etc?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, web, time

I am interested in creating a web game (in the likes of travian.com). I have some knowledge in php, sql and javascript. My question is this:

**What is the best way to create dynamic time-based events like building construction times,etc?**

I am specifically speaking of events that automatically change database after a certain period of time. From what I can gather one could use chron to query the database for updates on buildings constructions times and update them if, for example, the building time it takes + the time construction started = current time.
This would be one solution (which I don't like as most webs ervers only allow for 1 minute interval chrons).

Another solution seems to be using mysql events in which every time a user asks for a building to be constructed we would create an object on the database and update it after the event is fired. This to me seems to be the most intuitive answer.

I don't, however, have enough experience or know-how to figure out if there is a better solution or if these solutions are in any way viable for such "large" purposes.

If anyone could give me some lights on the issue or maybe point me in the correct direction I would me most appreciated. I apologize in advance as English is not my first language.

Comment: This post will give you some useful suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122954/timed-events-with-php-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer here depends on whether the updates you need to make are time-driven or event-driven, and on whether they are exclusively updates to other parts of the database.

If they are purely event-driven and purely updates to the database, then SQL Triggers can be a viable option. Even then, opinions in the industry are mixed about whether using Triggers is a good practice, as it can make it difficult for future developers to find the cause of a change. Another downside to triggers is that it can lead to slower performance to the user at the time the update is made (since the database has more complicated work to do than the initial update would have been).

If the updates are time-driven, or they include updates to anything outside of the scope of the database itself (e.g. sometimes updating the filesystem), or you want to avoid Triggers to simplify maintenance for future developers, then the cron-job approach is a great option. The one gotcha here is that a large collection of updates scheduled via cron job can result in a performance drain, so you will need to mitigate that when implementing the job (choosing an off time is one option here, as is implementing a queue system to run the updates, so that the cron job only issues a certain number of updates before letting other database requests go through).

Personally, I prefer a cron-job + queued update process.

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, than you for you comment. Maybe i haven't explained myself properly and i apologize. What i was thinking on using was MySQL Event Scheduler (I have no experience with this but sound like exaclty what i want). This sounds more or less like a timed Trigger so i expect your answer covers it. I am not so sure however how to correctly implement it on a chron basis. Imagine a certain event is schedule to start at 14:30:45 and chron runs precisely every minute (which seems to be the smallest interval available for most chron services) This would leave me with a 30 second gap no?